# python indeed api doesnt return more than 1025 results

Tags: python, api, python-3.x

Here's the code i am trying:

```
from indeed import IndeedClient
client = IndeedClient(publisher = 97xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
params = {
    'q' : 'teradata',
    'userip' : "1.2.3.4",
    'useragent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2)",
    'limit': 5
    ,'start':1654
    ,'sort':'date'
}
search_response = client.search(**params)
```

The response tells you that there are 3222 total responses (which btw is not the same result you get if you actually search "teradata" on indeed but thats another issue).

now this should return 5 results from result #1654 onwards, however only returns 5 results from #1001. in fact adjusting the 'start' variable anywhere above 1000 is completely ineffective.

this is a pretty old api (https://github.com/indeedlabs/indeed-python) so I'm not sure if this simply wasnt updated or something. Is there a way around this limit please?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed API allows a maximum of 1025 results per query and as it returns a maximum of 25 results per API call, you will have up to 41 pages per query.

Comment: haha its been 3 years so i dont even remember this. cheers tho

Comment: I was doing something similar and came across this post - thought to update with my findings :)

Comment: i was a much noobier programmer back then :) i hope you found what you needed.

Comment: Looking for a way to bypass the 1025 results per query limit. No success in it yet.

Comment: is webscraping with selenium an option? thats always the fallback.

Comment: Selenium is indeed the fallback but it will be an overkill in current scenario. I will think about it only if the client pushes too hard.